# Retrofit 2.0 non-beta, using GsonConverterFactory

Tags: android, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to use the release version of Retrofit 2.0 and the GsonConverterFactory suggested on their [Retrofit configuration](http://square.github.io/retrofit/#restadapter-configuration).

The problem is that GsonConverterFactory seems to be only available for Retrofit 1, and I'm now I'm retrofit 2, even when GsonConverterFactory is on beta of 2.

Here are my Gradle dependencies:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

I can't find a non-beta version of converter-gson, and just removing the `-beta2` doesn't do the trick.

When running this code:

```
import retrofit.GsonConverterFactory;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class Service {

    public void getListings()
    {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("http://www.google.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Services services = retrofit.create(Services.class);
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
addConverterFactory (retrofit2.Converter.Factory) in Builder cannot be applied to (gson.GsonConverterFactory)
```

Any suggestions, aside from running retrofit 2 beta?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation on the retrofit's website, they say that you should use `com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson`

in your `build.gradle` replace

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

with

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

Comment: Needs the 2.0.0 at the end, and it works!. Thanks. Probably edit the answer so I can mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Pramod was close to it. This works:

```
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
```

It needs the `2.0.0` at the end.

Comment: in this case you should notify the square guys then,because on their website they have com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson not compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0' it will confuse other people

Comment: Exactly! I'll email them